# How can I use a single table from an external database on a site which uses an identical second database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, external

I have two websites which I want to have them use the same user table in MySQL.

One site has no users, the other has 20,000+ users. Let's call the site with no users Site1 and the site with 20k users site2.

I want people who sign up on either site1 or site2 to have the same account on both sites without having to set up two accounts.

Both sites use the exact same data structure for the users table, so if I could use the users table for site2 on site1, then both sites could use the same table. That is to say, users who sign up on site1 will also automatically have an account on site2.

The seemingly easy way would be to just import the users table from site1 to site2, now it's duplicated. However, it is not so easy.

site1 has regular users signing up, 30 to 50 per day; and once I set up this new strategy it will be self--marketing, so I will also be getting users for site2.

As you see, it isn't feasible to be importing new users one by one, and isn't reasonable to import users every single day.

So what I would like to do, is to get site2 to simply use the external database from site1.

Please note that both site1 and site2 are on the same server, in the same cpanel with the same phpmyadmin. So we don't have to worry about remote access to another server since they are on the same server. However they have a different database name (of course) and a different database user/pass.

Also I can't merge the databases into one database because the tables all have the same names but different data (two different sites but use the same database system). Otherwise changes to site2 would also change site1 or vice-versa, which I don't want because they are two different websites.

So, how can I allow site2 to use just one external (but on the same server) table (users table) from the site1 database?

Comment: Yes you can do. From site1, if the user is logging in check in site1 database whether the user is in the database or not if yes allow the user to login. if not available, create another mysql_pconnect which will return the new db connection store it in $conn2 variable. using this new connection variable you can check in site2 db now. if user available let him login. same process from site2 if the user is from site2.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about cpanel and I'm not sure to what extent the service is managed by your hosting company, but I would guess it should be possible to make the code of site2 connect to the database of site1 for specific queries. Just make a separate connection with site1's database name (and access credentials).

If that's not possible, another option is to create a sort of API layer in site1's code, and expose this API via, say, HTTPS, to site2 (i.e. site2's code would use HTTP functions (such as the curl library) to communicate with site1 and perform authentication-related functions (i.e. log in, register, etc...).

The first approach would likely be much easier to implement. The second approach may be more scalable if you have more sites in the future or want to be more flexible about the databases structure, where they are hosted, who has direct access to them, etc...

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am asking about how to do, to *"make the code of site2 connect to the database of site1 for specific queries"*. Exactly. So how can I do this?

Comment: How does site2 connect to the database of *site2*? Do you pass the database server domain? port? user? password? Simply pass those of site1...

Comment: Both sites access the databases through a global config file which contains the access details.

Comment: At some place in your code you actually create a connection, right? Using mysql_connect() or something of that sort. To connect you pass parameters with information about the server to connect to, right? So specifically for authentication you can grab another set of parameters (those of the database of *site1*) (from the same configuration file or from another one) and pass them instead of the "usual" parameters...

Answer (score 0):

You have some options to do this. for example you can create an script to read new users on one database and insert them to the second database, then run this script with cron job every minute.

The second option is to connect to Site2 database and query on users table on that database for Site1 (for authentication, read, etc). but the disadvantage is that you can't join this table with your other tables in Site1 database.

Another option will be replicating your users table. you can search for MySQL replication for more information.